# Command-line option '--what-if' in makefile does not work

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From theGNU Make [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html#Instead-of-Execution):***

> `-W FILE`
>   
>   `--what-if=FILE`
>   
>   `--assume-new=FILE`
>   
>   `--new-file=FILE`
>
> ```
>  "What if".  Each '-W' flag is followed by a file name.  The given
>  files' modification times are recorded by 'make' as being the
>  present time, although the actual modification times remain the
>  same.  You can use the '-W' flag in conjunction with the '-n' flag
>  to see what would happen if you were to modify specific files.
> ```

***And there, [elsewhere](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary):***

> '-W FILE'
>   
>   '--what-if=FILE'
>   
>   '--new-file=FILE'
>   
>   '--assume-new=FILE'
>
> ```
>  Pretend that the target FILE has just been modified.  When used
>  with the '-n' flag, this shows you what would happen if you were to
>  modify that file.  Without '-n', it is almost the same as running a
>  'touch' command on the given file before running 'make', except
>  that the modification time is changed only in the imagination of
>  'make'.  *Note Instead of Executing Recipes: Instead of Execution.
> ```

***So, given a makefile:***

```make
# 'all' is "up-to-date", when it is "checked" against its prerequisites 'foo'.
$(shell touch foo)
$(shell sleep 1)
$(shell touch all)

all : foo
    echo '$@'

foo : phony
    : blah blah

.PHONY : phony
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
# 'all' would-be "up-to-date", when it is "checked" against its prerequisites 'foo'.
$ touch 'foo'
$ sleep 1
$ touch 'all'

# To quote the documentation, cited above, we:
# "Change the modification-time in the imagination of Make", for the file: 'foo'
$ make --new-file='foo'
: blah blah
```

No commands were executed for the file 'all', despite the explicit command-line option `--new-file=foo`, that was supposed to change the modification-time in the "imagination" of Make, as explained in the quote above.

Comment: interesting. what actually gets run? `blahblah`?

Comment: there is a problem i noticed in your test. for the first run of make. all commands should be run, shouldn't them?

Comment: just had a look. maybe this flag is different from what you think it is. try to delete your line of `.PHONY` and compare `make` with `make --new-file=phony`.

Answer (score 1):

OK. your understanding to this flag is wrong. `gnu make` keeps track of the files generated. your test program is bazaar, because nothing is generated from the dependencies.

in your original program:

```
foo : phony
    : blah blah

.PHONY : phony
```

`phony` is a pseudo target, which `make` shall mandatorily run it and the targets that depends on it. that's the reason your code for `foo` target gets run -- it has nothing to do with the state of the file `foo` in your file system.

since `all` depends on `foo`, however, to generate `foo`, **the modification time before running the command and after are the same**, so at `make`'s point of view, there is no need to generate `all` at all, which is very much expected behavior for common `make` usage.

---

following is my code to demonstrate what this flag is for:

```
all : foo
        touch all

foo : phony
        touch foo
```

then in your console:

```
$ touch phony && make
touch foo
touch all
```

then again:

```
$ make
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

the reason should be obvious. then if i add that flag:

```
$ make --new-file=phony
touch foo
touch all
```

now you shall see.

the difference here, is in `make`'s imaginary, the dependency `phony` has been modified, therefore the whole dependency tree needs to be refreshed too.

if we combine the documentation:

> When used
>    with the '-n' flag, this shows you what would happen if you were to
>    modify that file.

this makes a lot of sense, because it allows me to probe the dependency tree and see how many things need to be rebuilt if i modify this file.

Comment: "since `all` file has been there, so there is no reason to try to generate an existing file." Well, there **is** a reason, as it is out-of-date when checked against its dependency `foo`, (given the modification-time in the "imagination" of Make for `foo` (per the `--new-file` option)).

Comment: @JiCha ok. copy my example and run it in your machine. then pass in `--new-file=foo` and see what `make` will do. i would say the unexpected thing you found out in your code is because you don't actually generate any file by `make`.

Comment: @JiCha i would argue the logic underneath `make` would be this: you claimed `all` depends on `foo`, so we try to generate `foo` first, then we found out the fact that **the modification time before running the command and after are the same**, so we can conclude that we don't have to generate `all`. i hope that gives you explanation.

Comment: "the modification time before running the command and after are the same, so we can conclude that we don't have to generate `all`".
**not** true. A simple case, where `foo` is **truly** later than `all`, run some `blah command` for `foo`. Make will re-build `all`.

Comment: @JiCha hold your opinion then. i've done my best to explain such phenomenon in your special case. just to remind you a basic principle in software: [garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).